# Python float decimal places

Tags: python

In python, suppose I want to quickly and easily format my float number to two or less decimal places, for example:

```
1.234 -> 1.23

1.2 -> 1.2

1  -> 1

2. -> 2
```

What method should I use? I can format it to 2 decimal places fixed but can not think of a quick way to make it 2 or less decimal places.

Comment: use the Decimal() class.  http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend using the `round` function

```
In [1]: round(1.234, 2)
Out[1]: 1.23

In [2]: round(1.2, 2)
Out[2]: 1.2
```

Unfortunately, it has one drawback: it will convert your `int`s to `float`s (in python2.x. It'll keep them as `int`s in python3.x, though):

```
In [3]: round(1,2)
Out[3]: 1.0
```

Comment: Can find more documentation/details on the above round() if you need on [Python Documentation - Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues)

Answer (score 2):

For formatted printing use:

```
print "%.2f" % 1.234  # -> 1.23
print "%.1f" % 1.234  # -> 1.2
print "%.0f" % 2.     # -> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a little brute force after formatting to two places.

```
>>> '{:.2f}'.format(1.234).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
'1.23'
>>> '{:.2f}'.format(1.2).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
'1.2'
>>> '{:.2f}'.format(1).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
'1'
>>> '{:.2f}'.format(2.).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
'2'
```